# Creating Linked List, not passing back to Main

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

So I am creating a linked list in a separate function, and when I print out the linked list within the function, it seems everything is fine. However; when I go to main and try to access the linked list with printf I get a segmentation fault and am confused exactly why.

```
void createLL(struct node* head, struct node* curr, char ch, int number){
//lowest digit is the head
    while (((scanf(" %c",&ch)) >= 0)){
        curr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*)); //allocate space
        number = ch - '0' ; //convert char to number
        curr->data = number;
        curr->next = head;
        head = curr;
    }
    curr = head;
    //troubleshoot
    while(curr){
        printf("%d\n",curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr = head;
    printf("%d\n",curr->data);
}

int main(){
    //initials
    int i, number; 
    char ch;
    //node pointers
    struct node* headOne = NULL;
    struct node* currOne = NULL;
    struct node* headTwo = NULL;
    struct node* currTwo = NULL;
    //create linked list
    createLL(headOne,currOne, ch, number);
    printf("%d\n",currOne->data);
    createLL(headTwo,currTwo, ch, number);
    printf("%d\n",currTwo->data);
```

Comment: 'createLL(headOne,currOne, ch, number);' That cannot work: it cannot possibly change 'headOne', which will be forever NULL.

Comment: Extending Martin comment, you'll need to pass pointer to pointers in createLL so that you can modify the lists declared in main within the routine. That is, the signature of createLL would be something like: void createLL(struct node ** head, struct node** curr, char ch, int number)

Comment: Also, please note that about half the LL questions posted on SO have that issue, and there are a LOT.

Comment: Alternative to double stars: return the head; 'headOne=createLL(headOne,currOne, ch, number);'

Comment: sigh! `void` function, but "return" a value by argument ... tssssss

Answer (score 2):

In C functions pass all parameters by value.  So if you want to change a variable in a function, you need to pass the address of that variable and dereference the parameter in the function.

Also, you're not allocating the right amount of space for your node.  You want `sizeof(struct node)`, not `sizeof(struct node *)`.

```
void createLL(struct node **head, struct node **curr, char ch, int number){
//lowest digit is the head
    while (((scanf(" %c",&ch)) >= 0)){
        // don't cast the return value of malloc
        *curr = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //allocate space
        number = ch - '0' ; //convert char to number
        (*curr)->data = number;
        (*curr)->next = *head;
        *head = *curr;
    }
    *curr = *head;
    //troubleshoot
    while(*curr){
        printf("%d\n",(*curr)->data);
        *curr = (*curr)->next;
    }
    *curr = *head;
    printf("%d\n",(*curr)->data);
}


int main(){
    //initials
    int i, number; 
    char ch;
    //node pointers
    struct node* headOne = NULL;
    struct node* currOne = NULL;
    struct node* headTwo = NULL;
    struct node* currTwo = NULL;
    //create linked list
    createLL(&headOne,&currOne, ch, number);
    printf("%d\n",currOne->data);
    createLL(&headTwo,&currTwo, ch, number);
    printf("%d\n",currTwo->data);
}
```

Comment: hrmm, now I'm picking up this

error: request for member ‘data’ in something not a structure or union

Comment: @ user3260745 probably a typo.  Post the offending code as an update, but leave the original code.

Comment: yeah, I was trying to the point the pointer of curr to data without resolving it first. I think it was a order of precedence error.