# Linked list, doesnt work when passing head of the list as argument in function

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Whats the problem when passing head of the list as parameter in function ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node* next;

}node;
node* h1 = NULL;

void ubaci(int x, node *head)
{
    node *novi = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    novi->value = x;
    novi->next = head;
    head = novi;
}

void ispisi(node *head)
{
    node *temp = head;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> ",temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;

    while(x<10)
    {
        x++;
        ubaci(x,h1);
    }
    ispisi(h1);

    return 0;
}
```

This doesnte work, i cant figure out why. But when i try to use these functions without passing head of the list as argument and using global variable instead it works perfectly.
Example:

```
void ubaci(int x)
{
    node *novi = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    novi->value = x;
    novi->next = h1;
    h1 = novi;
}

void ispisi()
{
    node *temp = h1;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> ",temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: About half of the thousands of linked-list questions asked on SO have this exact issue - changing head locally and not returning it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350749/creating-linked-list-not-passing-back-to-main

Answer (score 0):

Function parameters are its local variables. Any change of a local variable does not influence on the original argument.

You should pass arguments by reference if you want to change them in a function.

For example

```
void ubaci(int x, node **head)
{
    node *novi = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    novi->value = x;
    novi->next = *head;
    *head = novi;
}
```

A function call can look like

```
ubaci( x, &h1 );
```